# Paper replication coding task for computer science Ph.D students

Tags: phd, code

I want to ask about the specific task given by an advisor to their students, consisting of a paper replication coding task. The task involves writing a lot of code as to implement the paper's algorithm.
The task is given to a final year student while no support or help is provided to them, so that the student should work alone on doing that.

How common is it is academia to see such things as Ph.D. students writing a lot of code on complex algorithm all the time during their PhD period with no help (nor brainstorming meetings..)?

Comment: What is the purpose of such a task for a final year PhD student?

Comment: I'm not in CS, but I would assume that ability to write code independently is a fairly common expectation for CS PhD students, even if some areas of CS don't rely much on code.

Comment: I agree that the skill is valuable and expected. But in their final year, a PhD student is expected to start finishing up their own original research and write a thesis. Giving them a task at this stage to test if they can write code independently seems far too late and potentially distracting.

Comment: @dubious I think we're missing a lot of background here, but OP's objection seems to be focused on the *no help/no support* aspects rather than being busy with a thesis. It could be that the algorithm is important for contextualizing results in OP's thesis. It would be best if OP could clarify, though.

Comment: @dubious I never said it was to test their abilities to code.

Comment: so in the final year of Ph.D. it is rare to get such tasks as writing code? When should students start writing their dissertations anyway?

Comment: It was not clear what you were saying. Hence the question :). Can you please elaborate more on the task and what it is for.

Comment: the task of replicating a paper is rather for professors and post-docs is what I thought, or at least for more experienced staff, rather than for PhD students

Comment: @MartinMoore What would make you think that?

Comment: What part of the world are you in? From my perspective (US), your question seems so bizarre that I have to wonder if you really are a CS PhD student. But, things do work differently in different places.

Comment: To be clear: Do you not have any dissertation started? Do you have a timeline for when that should start and end?

Answer (score 4):

In most fields in Computer Science, the capability of implementing an algorithm is expected from students with a Ph.D. In those fields, the majority of theses will have a comparison between different methods, some proposed by the thesis and some based on the state of the art. To compare, one has to measure and this implies that methods will have to be implemented.

Unfortunately, until quite recently, many people in CS published their results without publishing their code. This is finally changing, as much larger data sets and auxiliary files can be made accessible. But even if implementations are available, they need to be comparable, which usually means re-engineering large parts of the code.

A Ph.D. especially in Computer Science is a bit of an apprenticeship. You usually will have to develop a capacity to code and to code well if you are working in Systems or on the tool-development side of Machine Learning inter alia. If a student is in their final year and still cannot code, then something went really wrong. The students should have been set to this task early on. But even in their final year, a student is expected to contribute to the research of the group, and this could mean implementing an algorithm given in a paper. There might not be a choice if the algorithm or data structure is new and pertinent to the thesis topic.

I do not see the reason to have brain-storming session. The paper might be a bit obscure (sometimes by design in order to not leak intellectual property), but should have enough information for a skilled engineer to regenerate the implementation. Also, research implementations are not "industrial-strength" and often can break under rare circumstances (because assumptions were made and not checked).

I assume that I might give you different advice if you were to give us a more complete description of your situation. But in many fields in CS, it is common to spend most of your time implementing and then measuring. For crying out loud: Just go and do a google search on Phase Change Memory and B-trees. I would guess that most of the papers represent the core of a Ph.D. thesis. Look at the graphs in the evaluation session and you will see comparisons with other ways of implementing B-trees. Each way represents a lot of coding work. Professors in a good research group are busy developing and pitching ideas to funding agencies and usually do not have the time to implement other people's algorithms. They also have to teach and run meetings with their graduate students.

So, it is common for Ph.D. students in C.S. to implement code and implement other people's algorithms as well as their own.

Comment: Papers *should* have enough information to replicate.  They often do not.

Comment: I must be walking on the moon reading such speech. I mean: "The paper might be a bit obscure, but should have enough information for a skilled engineer to regenerate the implementation" OR "Professors in a good research group are busy developing and pitching ideas to funding agencies and usually do not have the time to implement other people's algorithms" ? looking for funding isn't enough as a task for a professor submitting with their students a paper. Papers need clarification in a research group before student can do them, otherwise student is not working in a group